# Laravel 5.6: Cuando subo imagen guarda ruta pero no la imagen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

Cuando subo una imagen me guarda perfectamente la ruta de la imagen en la base de datos, cuyo campo es "image", pero no guarda la imagen como tal en la carpeta public como se lo especifico en el código.

En la vista create de mi proyecto uso Form, asi que lei que debia modificarlo de la siguiente manera para subir archivos:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'products.store', 'files' => True]) !!}
```

En el controlador tengo lo siguiente para los metodos "store" y "update":

```
//IMAGE
    if($request->file('image')){

        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image', $request->file('image'));

        $product->fill(['image' => asset($path)])->save();
    }
```

Tampoco me esta validando el tipo de imagen, pero los demas campos si. Dejo el codigo de las validaciones:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'  => 'required',
        'short' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ];

if($this->get('image'))
        $rules = array_merge($rules, ['image' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png']);

    return $rules;

}
```

Ya configure el fylesystems de config colocando la ruta root de la siguiente manera:

```
'root' => public_path(),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que correr el siguiente comando en tu projecto

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Este comando crea una carpeta llamada storage en la carpeta public, desde ahí podes accesar a las imágenes ya que laravel se encarga de mover la imagen a esta carpeta por si solo.

Con respecto a la validacion de la imagen, agrega esto a los rules

```
'imagen'          => 'image|max:1999|required'
```

Eso valida que sea imagen, con un tamaño maximo, y requerido.

Para validar el tipo, puedes hacer un custom rule de laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

Si creas el rule, la validacion quedaria de la siguiente forma

```
'imagen'          => ['image','max:1999','required', new miCustomRule]
```

Y recuerda hacer el use del archivo

```
use App\Rules\miCustomRule;
```

Espero te sirva.